# Div not fading with effect in Mozilla

Tags: jquery

I am using the following to fade a div with slideffect.

```
$('div.clsBlue').eq(2).fadeOut(1000, function() {

                   });
```

This fades with animation in IE7 perfectly but not in mozilla 3. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem: IE 6 worked fine, but FFox 3 didn't.

I solved this problem setting the container DIV

> height: auto

Regards.

Comment: I changed it to 50px. No effect still. I am jQuery 1.3.2

Comment: jQuery 1.3.1 and FFox 3.0.10.

Maybe you need initialize width property like the sample:

<div id="div1" style="clear: both; padding-left: 4em; margin-top: 1.5em; margin-bottom: 2em; width: 300px; height: 76px;">
 <div style="width: 200px;">
  <label>XYZ:</label>
 </div>
 <div style="margin-left: 2em; padding-top: 1em;">
  <div style="clear: both;">
   <div style="width: 150px; float: left;">
    <label>XYZ</label>
   </div>
   <div style="float: left; margin-left: 30px; width: 20px;">
    <input type="radio" value="v1" checked="checked" name="n1"/>
   </div>
  </div>
...

Answer (score 0):

Are you running in quirksmode? Sometimes if you don't have a specified doctype jQuery animations can do funny things.

Comment: I have a doctype <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Answer (score 0):

Check the DOM element you are fading has defined or browser-recognizable width and height values.

I was trying to fade a DIV element with an absolutely positioned anchor within - which doesn't work.  I then set explicit width and height for the DIV and set *position:absolute* to the DIV instead of the child anchor, so that the dimensions of the DIV can be picked up. Only then, will any jQuery fade work.